# Table TD Height in IE

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <table style = "width : 500px; height : 100%; border : 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
    <td style = "width : 300px; height : 100%; border : 1px solid;">
    1st TD

    </td>
    <td rowspan = 2 style = "border : 1px solid;">

    </td>
    <td rowspan = 2 style = "border : 1px solid;">
    Sidebar
    <br />
    <br />
    

    Sidebar
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style = "width : 300px; border : 1px solid;">
    Last TD
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I want that 1st TD should expand as I write text into it and the remaining space should be occupied by last TD.

This code works perfectly in Firefox but not in IE. IE equally divides 1st and Last TD across the rowspanned TDs.

You can yourself see the code in FF and IE and I want FF like look.

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <table style = "width : 500px; border : 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
    <td style = "height : 100%; border : 1px solid;">
    1st TD

    </td>
    <td rowspan = 2 style = "border : 1px solid;">

    </td>
    <td rowspan = 2 style = "border : 1px solid;  height : 100%; vertical-align : top;">
    Sidebar
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Sidebar
    <br />
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdffdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
    <td style = " border : 1px solid;">
    Last TD
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Please check my this code in FF and IE and see the difference of 1st and Last TD.

Comment: Hi Shivom Laksh, I tested your code in both Firefox and IE9, and I get the exact layout. What version of IE you are using?

Comment: If that's your actual code it's not even close to valid.

Comment: @shivom if my answer worked for you so can you mark it correct so this question will get attention to users that this question have valid answer.

Comment: Please do not post answers as follow up questions or discussion. Stack overflow is not a forum. Edit your question to provide additional detail, or use the comment facility under answers to request clarification.

Comment: why don't you put height:100% on the last td instead of 1st td? the last td will try to maximize its height after 1st td.

Answer (score 0):

@Shivom IE always render the tables code differently and IE7 and IE8 is different. So for your problem here is the code you can check it it will not give any error/problem in your requiremt and full browser compatible.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>1st TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/>Last TD<br/></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    Sidebar
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Sidebar
    <br />
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdffdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    fdkdf
    <br />
    dfkdf
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ShivomLaksh If this solved your problem, you should accept and/or up vote the answer (the check button on the left accepts, and the up/down arrows allow you to vote).  You should also not answer a question, not even your own, unless it is an actual answer (as in: a solution). Please see the FAQ!